# Angularjs - why is not calling that function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

i wanna call a function when the app starts to show a modal, so i did ...

I call the function with the `onDeviceReady`

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    function onDeviceReady() {
      openModal();  
    }
```

but the function is not calling, in console shows:
Uncaught ReferenceError: openModal is not defined

The function on controller:

```
$scope.openModal = function() {
      alert("funcionou!");
    $scope.modal.show();
  };
```

please help!

Comment: `openModal` and `$scope.openModal` are two different things (one of them does not exist).

Comment: @trincot , how i do call that scope function?

Comment: eh... you add parentheses after it?

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not know your scope.

You can run it when the controller is loaded.

Like this:

```
angular.module("controllers",[])
.controller("testController",
    function ($scope) {

        $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded',
            function () {
                $scope.modal.show()
            });
    });
```